# В чем разница между файлами CMD и BAT

Tags: cmd, bat

В чем разница между файлами `.cmd` и `.bat`? Есть ли конкретные рекомендации по использованию? Если `.cmd` более современный формат, почему мы до сих пор используем `.bat` чаще (включая "батники" в разговорах)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148968/windows-batch-files-bat-vs-cmd

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347593/whats-the-difference-between-bat-and-cmd-file

Comment: ну включайте в разговор `цэмэдэщьник`

Comment: @Sergey если по делу нечего сказать, не надо писать пустые комментарии.